# Developing a correct understanding of waitpid() and getpid()

Tags: c, unix, pid, waitpid

I am learning about `forks`, `execl` and parent and child processes in my systems programming class. One thing that is confusing me is `waitpid()` and `getpid()`. Could someone confirm or correct my understanding of these two functions?

**getpid()** will return the process ID of whatever process calls it. If the parent calls it, it returns the pid of the parent. Likewise for the child.  (It actually returns a value of type `pid_t`, according to the manpages).

**waitpid()** seems more complex. I know that if I use it in the parent process, without any flags to prevent it from blocking (using `WNOHANG`), it will halt the parent process until the child process terminates. I'm a little unsure as to how `waitpid()` manages all this, however. `waitpid()` also returns `pid_t`. What is the value of the `pid_t` `waitpid()` returns? How does this change depending on whether or not a parent or child calls it, and whether or not a child process is still running, or has terminated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding of `getpid` is correct, it returns the PID of the running process.

`waitpid` is used (as you said) to block the execution of a process (unless
`WNOHANG` is passed) and resume execution when a (or more) child of the process
ends. `waitpid` returns the `pid` of the child whose state has changed, -1 on
failure. It also can return 0 if `WNOHANG` has specified but the child has not
changed the state. See:

> *man waitpid*
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> `waitpid()`: **on success, returns the process ID of the child whose state has changed; if `WNOHANG`
>   was specified and one or more child(ren) specified by pid exist, but have not yet changed state,
>   then 0 is returned.**  On error, -1 is returned.

Depending on the arguments passed to `waitpid`, it will behave differently. Here
I'l quote the man page again:

> *man waitpid*
>
> ```
> pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *wstatus, int options);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The `waitpid()` system call suspends execution of the calling process until a child specified by pid  argument
>   has  changed  state.   By default, `waitpid()` waits only for terminated children, but this behavior is modifiable
>   via the options argument, as described below:
>
> The value of pid can be:
>
> - `< -1`: meaning wait for any child process whose process group ID is equal to the absolute value of `pid`.
> - `-1`: meaning wait for any child process.
> - `0`: meaning wait for any child process whose process group ID is equal to that of the calling process.
> - `> 0`: meaning wait for the child whose process ID is equal to the value of pid.
>
> The value of `options` is an OR of zero or more of the following constants:
>
> - `WNOHANG`: return immediately if no child has exited.
> - `WUNTRACED`  also  return  if a child has stopped (but not traced via ptrace(2)).
>     Status for traced children which have stopped is provided even if this option is not specified.
> - `WCONTINUED` (since Linux 2.6.10) also return if a stopped child has been resumed by delivery of `SIGCONT`.

- > I'm a little unsure as to how waitpid() manages all this

`waitpid` is a syscall and the OS handles this.

- > How does this change depending on whether or not a parent or child calls it, and whether or not a child process is still running, or has terminated?

`wait` should only be called by a process that has executed `fork()`. So the parent
process should cal `wait()`/`waitpid`. If the child process hasn't called
`fork()`, then it doesn't need to call either one of these functions. If however
the child process has called `fork()`, then it also should call
`wait()`/`waitpid()`.

The behaviour of these function is very well explained in the man page, I quoted the important parts of it. You should read the whole man page
to get a better understanding of it.

Answer (score 3):

`waitpid` "shall only return the status of a child process" (from the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html)).  So the `pid_t` waitpid returns belongs to one of the current or former children of the process calling `waitpid`.  For example, if a child has recently terminated, it returns that child's PID.

`waitpid` is only useful when called from a parent process.  If called from a process that does not have any children, it returns `ECHILD`.

`waitpid` can check the status of children that have terminated, or that has recently stopped or continued (e.g., `^Z` from a shell).  The various pid/option argument combinations in the spec tell you the various types of information you can return.  For example, the `WCONTINUED` option requests status of recently-continued children instead of recently-terminated children.

Comment: Will it return the `pid_t` of the child process upon the child terminating? I suppose that's where my confusion lies; I'm not sure 'when' `waitpid()` returns a value.

Comment: @ChrisT the man page is very clear when `waitpid` returns what, please read the man page.

Comment: @ChrisT Edited.  I know the spec is fairly dense, but it's all in there somewhere :) .